# Generate a column containing the time in minutes - in R

Tags: r, time

in R

I have a data-frame with 24400 observations (rows). In this data-frame I have a column df$hours containing hours index (as shown below). Basically each hour is repeated over around ~ 60 times before passing to the next hour until reaching the 23rd hour then it goes back again to "o" (example below

df$hours

```
1] "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00"
[12] "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00"
[23] "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00"
[34] "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00"
[45] "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00"
[56] "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01"
[67] "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01"
[78] "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01"
[89] "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01"
[100] "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01"
[111] "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "02"
[122] "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02"
[133] "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02"
[144] "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02"
[155] "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02"
[166] "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02"
[177] "02" "02" "02" "02" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03"
[188] "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03"
[199] "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03"
[210] "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03"
[221] "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03"
[232] "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "04" "04"
[243] "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04"
[254] "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04"
[265] "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04"
[276] "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04"
[287] "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04"
[298] "04" "04" "04" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05"
[309] "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05"
[320] "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05"
[331] "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05"
[342] "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05"
[353] "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "06" "06" "06"
[364] "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06"
[375] "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06"
[386] "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06"
[397] "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06"
[408] "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06" "06"
[419] "06" "06" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07"
[430] "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07"
[441] "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07"
[452] "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07"
[463] "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07"
[474] "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "07" "08" "08" "08" "08"
[485] "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08"
[496] "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08"
[507] "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08"
[518] "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08"
[529] "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08" "08"
[540] "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18"
[551] "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18"
[562] "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18"
[573] "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18"
[584] "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "18"
[595] "18" "18" "18" "18" "18" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19"
[606] "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19"
[617] "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19"
[628] "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19"
[639] "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19"
[650] "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "19" "20"
[661] "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20"
[672] "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20"
[683] "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20"
[694] "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20"
[705] "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20" "20"
[716] "20" "20" "20" "20" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21"
[727] "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21"
[738] "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21"
[749] "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21"
[760] "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21"
[771] "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "21" "22" "22"
[782] "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22"
[793] "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22"
[804] "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22"
[815] "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22"
[826] "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22" "22"
[837] "22" "22" "22" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23"
[848] "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23"
[859] "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23"
[870] "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23"
[881] "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23"
[892] "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "23" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00"
[903] "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00"
[914] "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00"
[925] "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00"
[936] "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00"
[947] "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00" "00"
[958] "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01"
[969] "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01"
[980] "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01"
[991] "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01"
[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 23459 entries ]
```

my aim is to generate another column df$minutes that shows the minutes within each hour. for example if we start following the order I gave it's gonna be

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 0 | 3 |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| 1 | 61 |
| 1 | 62 |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| 23 | 1380 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 0 | 3 |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| 1 | 61 |
| 1 | 62 |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| 23 | 1380 |
| 0 | 1 |

please not 2 things:
1- I don't have the same exact number of minutes in each hours (sometimes it is 60 sometimes it is less)
2- I don't have all hours of the day (there is a gap between 8-18)

I tried this but this is i think suggest that we have the same number of minutes for each hour (which is 60)

```
`timepf <- as.numeric(df$hours)
n <- length(timepf)

xtime <- numeric()
start <- 1
while (start <= n) {
  end <- min(start + 59, n)
  part <- timepf[start:end]
  xtime_part <- part * 60 + (1:length(part))
  xtime <- c(xtime, xtime_part)
  start <- end + 1
}
xtime
length(xtime)
`
```

xtime is the minutes column we're looking to create.

Comment: If the hour 01 was missing would minutes for hour 02 start at 61 or 121?

Comment: Minimize your example data, explain what happens when some hours are missing.

Comment: the hours that are missing each time are the hour from 8 to 18 (because I don't have any data for those. the last minute for the 8th hour would be (539) and the first in the 18th hour would be (1140). if hour 01 is missing minutes for 121 will start at 121. the issue is not when hours are missing, but minutes. if the last minute in hour 01 is missing hour 02 will start at 120 and that's what i'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I'll demonstrate using much smaller data, just 3 hours a day for only 4 minutes per hour.

```r
df <- data.frame(hour = rep(sprintf("%02i", rep(0:2, each=4)), 3))
```

Note that my code will assume full 60 minutes, though, so it should work as-is for your data.

The first thing we need to do, though, is account for "day": each time `hour` increments to `"00"` from something other than `"00"`, increment the day. After that, this is simply [summarize by group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272).

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(day = cumsum(hour == "00" & lag(hour != "00", default = FALSE))) %>%
  group_by(day, hour) %>%
  mutate(minute = as.integer(hour) * 60 + row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 36 × 3
#    hour    day minute
#    <chr> <int>  <dbl>
#  1 00        0      1
#  2 00        0      2
#  3 00        0      3
#  4 00        0      4
#  5 01        0     61
#  6 01        0     62
#  7 01        0     63
#  8 01        0     64
#  9 02        0    121
# 10 02        0    122
# # … with 26 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Take my word that on day = 1 (the second day) the `minute` resets to `1`. (Or look in the base-R code below, it's the values.)

## base R

```r
df$day <- cumsum(df$hour == "00" & c(FALSE, df$hour[-nrow(df)] != "00"))
df$day <- cumsum(df$hour == "00" & c(FALSE, df$hour[-nrow(df)] != "00"))
```

I'll note that if you think you may have a day restart lacking any of the `"00"` hours, you can use an alternate method to determine `day` by assuming that any *decrease* in `hour` means a new day:

```r
df$day2 <- cumsum(diff(as.integer(df$hour)) < 0)
```

From here, we'll use `ave`:

```r
df$minute <- ave(as.integer(df$hour), df[c("day","hour")], FUN = function(z) as.integer(z) * 60 + seq_along(z))
df
#    hour day minute
# 1    00   0      1
# 2    00   0      2
# 3    00   0      3
# 4    00   0      4
# 5    01   0     61
# 6    01   0     62
# 7    01   0     63
# 8    01   0     64
# 9    02   0    121
# 10   02   0    122
# 11   02   0    123
# 12   02   0    124
# 13   00   1      1
# 14   00   1      2
# 15   00   1      3
# 16   00   1      4
# 17   01   1     61
# 18   01   1     62
# 19   01   1     63
# 20   01   1     64
# 21   02   1    121
# 22   02   1    122
# 23   02   1    123
# 24   02   1    124
# 25   00   2      1
# 26   00   2      2
# 27   00   2      3
# 28   00   2      4
# 29   01   2     61
# 30   01   2     62
# 31   01   2     63
# 32   01   2     64
# 33   02   2    121
# 34   02   2    122
# 35   02   2    123
# 36   02   2    124
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer.

the thing is that I don't have exactly 60 observation for each hour they change they are either 60 or less.
in your df each is repeated 4 times

`df <- data.frame(hour = rep(sprintf("%02i", rep(0:2, each=4)), 3))`

while it is not the case. 

so instead of having
` [1] "00" "00" "00" "00" "01" "01" "01" "01" "02" "02" "02" "02"
[13] "00" "00" "00" "00" "01" "01" "01" "01" "02" "02" "02" "02"
[25] "00" "00" "00" "00" "01" "01" "01" "01" "02" "02" "02" "02"`
i have 

`[1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
[31] 1 2 2 2 2``

Comment: If you don't have 60 minutes per hour, how to you propose to "know" what minute each row accounts for? Am I misinterpreting what `minute` should be when a particular `hour`-group has a number of rows other than 60? If you have (say) 3 rows within one hour/day, are you expecting `minutes = c(0, 20, 40)`?

Comment: the thing is that I record sounds each recording period is one hour (60 minutes) but sometimes the recording is interrupted 1 or 2 minutes before. So instead of 1 hour there is only 57 minutes or 58 or 59, etc. so instead using your code which make sense and have things the easy way. I had to deal with these missing minutes.

Comment: If you are missing those minutes, and don't know which minutes those are, then the best you can do is "guess" and hope that your best-guess does not corrupt whatever study you're doing. Good luck, I hope you're able to fix it.